# Get-AzureRmLog -CorrelationId does not retrieve records as expected

Tags: azure, azure-diagnostics

I am retrieving activity log with the following commands

```
$ActivityLog = Get-AzureRmLog -StartTime $starttime -EndTime $endTime -WarningAction SilentlyContinue -MaxRecord $MaxRecords -Status 'Succeeded' 

$Output = $ActivityLog | Where-Object {$_.Authorization.Action -eq 'Microsoft.Resources/deployments/write'}
```

Next I am looping through the retrieve records and trying to get related records using correlationid - simplified code below.

```
foreach ($record in $output)
{
    $record.CorrelationId
    if($record.CorrelationId -eq $null -or $record.CorrelationId -eq ''){'error'}

    Get-AzureRmLog -CorrelationId $($record.CorrelationId) -WarningAction SilentlyContinue
    #EXPECTED this command to show me the original record and any related log entries.
}
```

In my case I am looping through each activity log record and I can verify using above script that I have a valid correlation ID for each record.

However when I try to get the related records using `Get-AzureRmLog -CorrelationId`, I get 0 results for many records. I can understand that some activities may not have more than one related entries in the log. However even for such cases, when I run `Get-AzureRmLog -CorrelationId`, I would expect that it would return that single activity log entry from which we originally retrieved the correlation id.

Why is the behavior like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible the Correlation ID's missing event records simply don't map to any events during the specified date-time window.

```
Get-AzureRMlog -CorrelationId "Insert Correlation ID here"
```

If run with a valid correlation id, will enumerate at most 1000 events  associated with the specified correlation ID within the last 7 days from the current date/time of execution. There's typically only one event outputted per correlation id.

As a test, I recommend handpicking a few of the correlation IDs you expect to see associating events for and separately run `Get-AzureRMlog` on each of them and validate the event output. Then run the same test against correlation IDs in your list with no events to compare. If no events listed then it means there were no event logs associated with the IDs during the time-frame.

This [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.insights/get-azurermlog?view=azurermps-5.5.0) has a few usage examples that may be useful in your investigation.

**Get an event log by correlation ID**

```
PS C:\>Get-AzureRmLog -CorrelationId "60c694d0-e46f-4c12-bed1-9b7aef541c23"
```

This command lists at most 1000 events associated with the specified correlation ID that took place 7 days from the current date/time. NOTE: this is usually only one event.

**Get an event log by correlation ID with a maximum number of events**

```
PS C:\>Get-AzureRmLog -CorrelationId "60c694d0-e46f-4c12-bed1-9b7aef541c23" -MaxEvents 100
```

This command lists at most 100 events associated with the specified correlation ID that took place 7 days from the current date/time. NOTE: this is usually only one event.

**Get an event log by correlation ID and start time**

```
PS C:\>Get-AzureRmLog -CorrelationId "60c694d0-e46f-4c12-bed1-9b7aef541c23" -StartTime 2017-05-22T04:30:00
```

This command lists at most 1000 events associated with the specified correlation ID that took place on or after 2017-05-22T04:30:00 local time if the start time is not older than 90 days from the current date/time. NOTE: this is usually only one event.

Comment: Thanks Femi Sulu.

I had opened a ticket with MSFT and it turns out they said there is a change in behavior of the cmdlet with newer versions.

For older Azure Rm modules, start time and end time is for 7 days. but newer modules take the start and end time as same day. I havent completely verified it, but for me specifying start and end time resolved it anyway.